# I want my log rotate to delete the log file which are older than 7 days

Tags: logrotate

I want logrotate to delete the log file which is older than 7 days. I have tried with maxage 7 but by not mentioning the rotate(count) keeps only one log after rotation, Again I have learned that logrotate will only do other stuff if it is able to rotate at least one file.
I have tried with something like this:
directory path/log.json {
size 1M
compress
maxage 5
missingok
}
Any help for the same wouold be appriciated.

Comment: Could you provide your log rotate configuration? `logrotate -d`

Comment: it looks like
/directory_path/*-xcc-log*.json {        
        size 10M
        compress
        maxage 7
        missingok
        }
not giving the rotate(count) keeps only one log.
But my requirement is to keep all the logs which are less than 7 days old.